# What is the detriment to using too-heavy weapons and armor and does it scale?

Tags: pixel-dungeon

According to the [Pixel Dungeon Wiki](http://pixeldungeon.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page), using weapons that are too heavy makes them slower to swing and less likely to hit, and using armor that is too heavy makes you slower to move and less likely to dodge.

Just how bad is this detriment? Does it scale with the difference between your strength and the item's requirement? (For example, with 13 strength, am I less likely to hit with an 18-strength warhammer than a 14-strength mace or is the detriment the same for both?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked this question on the wiki discussion page and received an answer (thanks to mdsimmo). I'm posting this as a wiki as it wasn't my work to discover it.

The [Required Strength](http://pixeldungeon.wikia.com/wiki/Game_mechanics/Required_strength) article in the wiki has been updated with formulas and examples, and the formulas are below.

Using overweight armor:

`speed (move speed in tiles per turn) = 
unburdenedSpeed × 1.3 ^ (heroStrength - requiredStrength)`

`dodge = unburdenedDodge / 1.5 ^ (requiredStrength - heroStrength)`

Using overweight weapons:

`accuracy = heroBaseAccuracy × weaponAccuracy / (1.5 ^ (requiredStrength - heroStrength))`

`delay (attack speed) = baseDelay × 1.2^(requiredStrength-heroStrength)`

It is clear that not only does the detriment scale, it does so by a significant amount.